# jQuery Validator Not Validating onkeyup

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, onkeyup

After reading a bunch of questions and applying "solutions" to them, I find that the jQuery validator is not validating `onkeyup`. Which by default, it should. I made sure that the source code was not modified by downloading a fresh file, nothing.

Version: jquery 1.10.2

```
Validation code:

/* check form */
$("#registerForm").validate({
/*  rules: {
    primaryPhone: {skip_or_fill_minimum: [2,'.firstPhoneSet']},
    contactPrimary: {skip_or_fill_minimum: [2,'.firstPhoneSet']},
    secondaryPhone: {skip_or_fill_minimum: [2,'.phoneNum2']},
    contactSecondary: {skip_or_fill_minimum: [2,'.phoneNum2']}
  }*/
    onkeyup: function(element)
    {
      $(element).valid();
    },
    errorElement: "span",
    rules: 
    {
        birthMonth: 
        {
          skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,'.dob']
        },
        birthDay: 
        {
          skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,'.dob']
        },
        birthYear: 
        {
          skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,'.dob']
        },
        resume: 
        {
          required: true,
          extension: "txt|doc|docx"
        },
        gender: 
        {
          required: true
        },
        ohlWhy:
        {
          required: true,
          wordCount: ['30']
        },
        coping:
        {
          required: true,
          wordCount: ['20']
        },
        intensity:
        {
          required: true,
          wordCount: ['20']
        }
    }
});
```

Note:

I HAVE tried running this code without

```
onkeyup: function(element)
{
  $(element).valid();
},
```

I also have a addClassRules method call:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
  field: 
  {
    required: true,
    minlength: 2
  },
  zip: 
  {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 5,
    maxlength: 5
  },
  years: 
  {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    minlength: 1,
    maxlength: 2
  },
  phoneNum: 
  {
    required: true,
    phoneUS: true
  },
    phoneNum2: 
  {
    required: false,
    phoneUS: true
  },
  dropList: 
  {
    required: true
  },
  dob: 
  {
    date: true,
    required: true
  },
});
```

And nothing. This is a solution I found on another question, but this gives me the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'valid'`

Which seems weird, because `.valid()` is a validator method.

The HTML has a LOT of input fields:

```
<form id="registerForm" action="index.cfm" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Basic Information</legend>
      <div class="insets">
          <label class="control-label" for="fName">First Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="fName" id="fName" class="field" value="<cfoutput>#session.fName#</cfoutput>" /><br />
          <label class="control-label" for="lName">Last Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="lName" id="lName" class="field" value="<cfoutput>#session.lName#</cfoutput>" /><br />
          <label class="control-label" for="nick">Nickname: <span class="optional">*optional</span></label>
          <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" value="<cfoutput>#session.nick#</cfoutput>" /><br />
      </div>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <input type="hidden" value="2" id="volType" name="volType" />
    <br />

    <!--- only show after choice has been made --->
    <div id="allInfo">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Contact Information</legend>
        <div class="insets">
          <label class="control-label" for="emailAddy">Email: </label>
          <input type="email" class="input-xlarge" name="emailAddy" id="emailAddy" required value="<cfoutput>#session.emailAddy#</cfoutput>" /><br />

          <!--- show only to shl vols --->
          <span id="shlOnly">
            <label class="control-label" for="rainnEmail">RAINN Email: </label>
            <input type="email" name="rainnEmail" class="input-xlarge" id="rainnEmail" required value="<cfoutput>#session.rainnEmail#</cfoutput>" /><br />
          </span>
          <!--- end show only --->

          <!--- only show to rcc and website vols --->
          <span id="rccANDwebs">
            <label class="control-label" for="address1">Address: </label>
            <input type="text" name="address1" class="input-xlarge field" id="address1" value="<cfoutput>#session.address1#</cfoutput>"/><br />
            <label class="control-label" for="address2">Apartment, Suite, etc: 
            <span class="optional">*optional</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="address2" class="input-xlarge" id="address2" value="<cfoutput>#session.address2#</cfoutput>" /><br />
            <label class="control-label" for="city">City: </label>
            <input type="text" class="field" name="city" id="city" value="<cfoutput>#session.city#</cfoutput>" /> <br />
          </span>
          <!--- end show only --->

          <label class="control-label" for="state">State: </label>
          <select id="state" class="input-mini dropList" name="state">
            <option value="">--</option>
           <cfoutput query="states">
                <option value="#states.id#" <cfif #session.state# EQ #states.id#>selected="selected"</cfif>>#states.stateName#</option>
            </cfoutput>
          </select>
          <label class="control-label" for="zip">Zip: </label>
          <input type="text" name="zip" class="input-small zip" id="zip" value="<cfoutput>#session.zip#</cfoutput>" />

          <label class="control-label" for="primaryPhone">Primary Phone: </label>
          <input type="text" class="input-medium phoneNum firstPhoneSet" name="primaryPhone" id="primaryPhone" placeholder="703-555-1010" value="<cfoutput>#session.primaryPhone#</cfoutput>" />
          <br /><span class="optional">Can we leave a message at this number?</span><br />

          <label class="radio inline" for="contactPrimaryYes">
            <input type="radio" checked name="contactPrimary" id="contactPrimaryYes" value="yes" />Yes 
          </label>

          <label class="radio inline" for="contactPrimaryNo">
            <input type="radio" name="contactPrimary" id="contactPrimaryNo" value="no" />No
          </label>

          <label class="control-label" for="secondaryPhone">Secondary Phone: 
         <span class="optional">*optional</span></label>

         <input type="text" class="input-medium phoneNum2" name="secondaryPhone" id="secondaryPhone" placeholder="703-555-1010" value="<cfoutput>#session.secondaryPhone#</cfoutput>" />
         <br /><span class="optional">Can we leave a message at this number?</span><br />

         <label class="radio inline" for="contactSecondaryYes">
            <input type="radio" name="contactSecondary" id="contactSecondaryYes" value="yes" <cfif IsDefined("session.contactSecondary") AND session.contactSecondary EQ "yes">checked</cfif> />Yes 
          </label>

          <label class="radio inline" for="contactSecondaryNo">
            <input type="radio" name="contactSecondary" id="contactSecondaryNo" value="no" <cfif IsDefined("session.contactSecondary") AND session.contactSecondary EQ "no">checked</cfif> />No
          </label>

        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <!--- if rcc or web --->
      <div class="form-actions" id="non-shlButton"> 
          <button type="submit" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-success">Continue to Step 2 &#187;</button>
      </div>

      <!--- if shl --->
      <div class="form-actions" id="shlButton">
          <button type="submit" style="float:right;" class="btn btn-primary">Submit My Application</button>
      </div>
    </div> <!--- end show after choice --->
  </form>
```

So my question is: why is my script only validating `onfocusout` and `onsubmit` only? (And why am I getting that error when it was the solution to several problems of the same type?)

Comment: `$(element).valid()` assumes that `valid` is a method attached to the jQuery.fn object since you have wrapped `element` in a jQuery selector. I'm not a Validator expert but try doing `console.log(element)` to see if it's something you really want to wrap in a jQuery selecion.

Comment: `<input type=​"text" name=​"fName" id=​"fName" class=​"field valid" value>​` which is the element I am typing into.

Comment: @rescuecreative @Mathletics this yields: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'valid'`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't actually suggest that. I just suggested you log it to the console and make sure you were using the right kind of object. It was an off-the-cuff suggestion because I'm not familiar with validator. Someone other than me will need to help with this.

Comment: @Sparky https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/541 I also just noticed weird behavior. When I come back to an invalid field, delete, and start typing, it performs correctly, but on an `onkeypress` style. I also have no idea what you mean unrelated. I added the validator classrules (Don't judge me, I didn't write the rules I'm just working with what I got lol), which links all classname "field" to the validator

Comment: [Read the developer's last comment (9 months ago) where he says he fixed that issue in version 1.11.1](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/541).

Comment: I have to walk away from this for a while but here's where I'm at with it.  [Working (plugin v1.10.0)](http://jsfiddle.net/dhf7Y/1) and [Not Working (plugin v1.11.1)](http://jsfiddle.net/dhf7Y/).  Can't yet explain why my original fiddle with 1.11.1 was working.

Comment: Have you tried downgrading the plugin to version 1.10.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to validator config:

```
onkeyup: function( element, event ) {
        if ( event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "" ) {
            return;
        } else {
            this.element(element);
        }
    },
```

It overwrites plugin's onkeyup function. It should works.

Now validation plugin works in different way. It first wait for user to enter text, than validate it and when some field was validated once than onkeyup works fine.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you for this answer. No more lazy validation!